# The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Tags: class, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am developing a machine learning program and I am stuck on this error.
Currently my dataset has 2 classes and looks like this:

```
2652,0.09,-1.02,0.43,-0.01,-0.94,0.35,1
1,0.38,-0.90,0.19,0.30,0.95,0.12,2
2653,0.09,-1.02,0.43,-0.01,-0.94,0.35,1
4,0.38,-0.90,0.19,0.29,0.96,0.06,2
5,0.38,-0.90,0.19,0.29,0.96,0.06,2
2654,0.15,-1.01,0.45,-0.01,-0.94,0.35,1
2,0.38,-0.90,0.19,0.29,0.96,0.06,2
```

And when I run my code I get this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c44a67b01cf1> in <module>
     11 model, params = train_model(X_train, y_train, 
     12                     est=SVC(probability=True),
---> 13                     grid={'C': param_range, 'gamma': param_range, 'kernel': ['linear']})
     14 eval_model(model, X_test, y_test, 'SVC')
     15 

<ipython-input-5-d902442b6ba1> in train_model(X, y, est, grid)
      2     print('::::Train Model::::')
      3     gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=est, param_grid=grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=4, n_jobs=-1)
----> 4     gs = gs.fit(X, y)
      5 
      6     return (gs.best_estimator_, gs.best_params_)
.
.
.
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class
```

But I've realised that in this part of the code

```
feats, y = get_simple_features(data, wsize='10s')
# split data into train and test sets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feats, y, test_size=.25, random_state=0, stratify=y)


print('Support Vector Machine')
model, params = train_model(X_train, y_train, 
                    est=SVC(probability=True),
                    grid={'C': param_range, 'gamma': param_range, 'kernel': ['linear']})
eval_model(model, X_test, y_test, 'SVC')
```

When I did `print(np.unique(y))`, the output is [[1](https://github.com/pauloaferreiraa/Thesis/blob/master/analysis.ipynb)].
And it happens in this line of code:

```
y = data['label'].resample(wsize, how=lambda ts: mode(ts)[0] if ts.shape[0] > 0 else np.nan)
```

Because data['label'] has both classes, but the result of the resample only 1 class.
However, I've asked another person to run my code and there is no error at all.

What can it be?

PS: [Here](https://github.com/pauloaferreiraa/Thesis/blob/master/analysis.ipynb) is the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the randomness of the resampling you are doing when running the `resample` function, specially since the sample size is too small (< 10) and it's not a stratified sampling, you are likely to get a sample that only represents a single class.